# failed to get cursor when querying URI table for a PDF file in the Downloads folder of an Android 11 device

Tags: android, android-studio, uri, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

On an Android 11 device, through SAF standard file selector, my app selects a PDF file which locates in the public folder Downloads.

In order to get its full path, I try to query the uri table through context.getContentResolver().query().

But now, **the cursor returned is not null while cursor.moveToFirst() == false.** As a result, my app failed to get the full path.

**What's wrong?**

My Android device: Android 11, Mi 12 Pro. The READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are all in manifest.

**code snippet a-**

```
//now, uri = "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A7755"

final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);  //now, id = msf:7755
final String[] split = id.split(":");
final String type = split[0];   //now, type="msf"
String strRealId = split[1];    //now, strRealId = 7755

final Uri contentUri;

contentUri =ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL),
                                    Long.valueOf(strRealId));
//contentUri =ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                    //Long.valueOf(strRealId));

//now, contentUri = "content://media/external/downloads/7755"

path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
```

**code snippet b -**

```
......
private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String column2 = "_id";
        final String[] projection = {column,column2};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

            //The row as below. step debug to here. I found cursor != null while cursor.moveToFirst() == false! What's wrong?
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);

                String strTest = "";
                int nTest = 0;

                 strTest = cursor.getString(column_index);
                 nTest = cursor.getInt(1);

                 return strTest;
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            String strError = e.getMessage();
        }
            finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

***Thank you all. Have a good weekend.*** :-)

Comment: "my app selects a PDF file which locates in the public folder Downloads" -- you have no means of forcing the user to choose from any particular document tree, or even forcing the user to pick a file on the filesystem. "What's wrong?" -- you are attempting to get a "full path". Use the `Uri` properly, such as by calling `openInputStream()` or `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My app complies with the SAF (Storage Access Framework) specification, through a standard system file picker, to pick a pdf file in the public folder Downloads. Second, for DownloadsDocument, is it no longer possible to query its uri table? Thanks again.

Comment: "My app complies with the SAF (Storage Access Framework) specification, through a standard system file picker, to pick a pdf file in the public folder Downloads" -- the user is not limited to `Downloads/`. "Second, for DownloadsDocument, is it no longer possible to query its uri table?" -- there is no "uri table".